# Access File Dialog Import- Import multiple excel tabs/sheets

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I have the following code that will allow me to select a specific spreadsheet and import it inside my table. The issue I have is that there are a total of 4 tabs (With all the same column headings, just different types of data).

Is it possible to have this import function, import the data in each tab (total of 4 tabs), into my table with a single import?

**Module:**

```
Function selectFile()
    Dim fd As FileDialog, fileName As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    fd.AllowMultiSelect = False

    If fd.Show = True Then
        If fd.SelectedItems(1) <> vbNullString Then
            fileName = fd.SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    Else
        'Exit code if no file is selected
        End
    End If

    'Return Selected FileName
    selectFile = fileName

    Set fd = Nothing

Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    Set fd = Nothing
    MsgBox "Error " & Err & ": " & Error(Err)

End Function
```

**Form:**

```
Private Sub cmdImport_Click()
    'Unset warnings
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    'Import spreadsheet
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "Table123", selectFile, True

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Added the following range (4 times due to 4 tabs/worksheets):

```
   Private Sub cmdImport_Click()

Dim selectFile() As String

    'Unset warnings
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    'Import spreadsheet
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acImport, _
                          SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
                          TableName:="Producer Pro Inquiries", _
                          fileName:=selectFile, _
                          HasFieldNames:=True, _
                          Range:="Medicare$"

      DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acImport, _
                          SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
                          TableName:="Producer Pro Inquiries", _
                          fileName:=selectFile, _
                          HasFieldNames:=True, _
                          Range:="Centene Medicare$"

         DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acImport, _
                          SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
                          TableName:="Producer Pro Inquiries", _
                          fileName:=selectFile, _
                          HasFieldNames:=True, _
                          Range:="Medsupp$"

           DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acImport, _
                          SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
                          TableName:="Producer Pro Inquiries", _
                          fileName:=selectFile, _
                          HasFieldNames:=True, _
                          Range:="Commercial$"

    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

When trying to import, when I select the file, the File Dialog box re-opens asking me to select the file again (keeps doing it).

Comment: Do you know in advance the tab names?

Comment: @Parfait Hello, Yes, I know the tab names in advance.

Comment: I was just going to answer to your updated code. Simply call `selectFile()` once at the beginning assigning it to a string variable. Use that string variable in `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet`.

Comment: @Parfait I added Dim selectFile() As String at the beginning but I get an Run-Time 2498 error. I updated the code above

Comment: You cannot call functions in `Dim`. See @KostasK.'s answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TransferSpreadsheet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-transferspreadsheet-method-access) method provides an additional field to set imported `Range`. You need to provide the range (sheet name) to the method.

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acImport, _
                          SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
                          TableName:="Table123", _
                          FileName:=selectFile, _
                          HasFieldNames:=True, _
                          Range:="Sheet1$"
```

Note: If the FileDialog's `Show` is not `0`, a selection has been made - no need to check for `vbNullString.`

```
If fd.Show <> 0 Then selectFile = fd.SelectedItems(1)
```

### Edit:

In you case it would be something like this:

```
Private Sub cmdImport_Click()

    Dim filepath As String
        filepath = selectFile()

    If Len(filepath) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    With DoCmd
        .SetWarnings False
        .TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acImport, _
                          SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
                          TableName:="Table123", _
                          FileName:=filepath, _
                          HasFieldNames:=True, _
                          Range:="ZZ$"
        .TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acImport, _
                          SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
                          TableName:="Table123", _
                          FileName:=filepath, _
                          HasFieldNames:=True, _
                          Range:="YY$"
         .TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acImport, _
                          SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
                          TableName:="Table123", _
                          FileName:=filepath, _
                          HasFieldNames:=True, _
                          Range:="XX$"
        .TransferSpreadsheet TransferType:=acImport, _
                          SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
                          TableName:="filepath", _
                          FileName:=selectFile, _
                          HasFieldNames:=True, _
                          Range:="WW$"
        .SetWarnings True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: K Since I have 4 sheets, how would I include that in the range? I can only enter one sheet in the range or my code throws an error.

Comment: You can only set one sheet each time. To import all sheets you will have to make four transfers `With DoCmd ... End With`.

Comment: K Just made the change and updated my post. The File dialog box keeps re-opening when selecting the file (asks me to select it again). Is my range correct?

Answer (score 2):

You can import multiple excel sheets, or even multiple files, in one go, by using SQL to query the Excel sheets and a union query.

You can, of course, use dynamic SQL to modify the file location and sheet names

```sql
SELECT *
INTO MyTable
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM [Sheet1$A:C] 
    IN 'C:\MyFile.xlsx'[Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=Yes;]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM [Sheet2$A:C]
    IN 'C:\MyFile.xlsx'[Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=Yes;]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM [Sheet3$A:C]
    IN 'C:\MyFile.xlsx'[Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=Yes;]
) u
```

Or, when using dynamic SQL:

```
Dim fileLocation As String
fileLocation = selectFile
Dim Range1 As String
Range1 = "ZZ$"
'Other ranges here
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT * INTO MyTable FROM (" & _ 
" SELECT * FROM [" & Range1 & "] " & _ 
" IN '" & fileLocation & "'[Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=Yes;]" & _ 
" UNION ALL" & _ 
" SELECT * FROM [" & Range2 & "] " & _ 
" IN '" & fileLocation & "'[Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=Yes;]" & _ 
" UNION ALL" & _ 
" SELECT * FROM [" & Range2 & "] " & _ 
" IN '" & fileLocation & "'[Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=Yes;]" & _ 
" ) u"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
```